# problema com nextLine() dentro do loop

Tags: java, entrada-de-dados

O usuário deve digitar nome e senha diferentes, enquanto forem iguais vai ficar no loop

```
...

Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

String nome, senha;

do{

System.out.println("Digite nome:");
nome = teclado.nextLine();

System.out.println("Digite senha:");
senha = teclado.next();

if(nome.equals(senha)){

System.out.println("Nome deve ser diferente de senha, Digite novamente");
}

} while(nome.equals(senha));

...
```

Quando nome e senha são iguais ele deveria retornar e pedir para digitar apenas o nome, só então depois pedir a senha, porém ele pede os 2 nome e senha, queria entender pq o `nextLine` faz isso e como deve fazer para usar ele nesse caso. obs: sei q o `next()` resolve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Nem tudo que esta na internet é verdadeiro ou é real.

Apesar de ser bastante difundido na internet o uso de instâncias da classe [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) como sendo um substituto para o uso do método [`java.io.Console.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) não é bem assim.

A classe `java.util.Scanner` é um scanner de texto que pode analisar tipos primitivos e strings usando expressões regulares.
`java.util.Scanner` divide sua entrada em [tokens](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_l%C3%A9xica) usando um delimitador padrão, que inicialmente corresponde a [espaços em branco](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)).

A [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#reader()) diz:

> Para aplicações simples que requerem apenas leitura orientada por linha, use `java.io.Console.readLine()`

Ou seja `java.util.Scanner` é ferramenta usada para fazer a análise léxica de um texto vindo de um objeto das classes [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html), [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), [`Readable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Readable.html), [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), [`ReadableByteChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html) ou [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html).

No caso da leitura do console é passado [`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) uma instância de `InputStream`.

## Queria entender por que o [`java.util.Scanner.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) faz isso e como fazer para o usar nesse caso?

O método `nextLine()` não é um método próprio para leitura de uma linha de caracteres. Ele é método para leitura caracteres excedentes, sejam caracteres não formem tokens ou caracteres descartados durante a análise léxica. `nextLine()` a partir do ultimo token lido e retorna o restante da entrada que foi ignorado. Como durante a primeira execução do loop ainda nenhum token foi lido pelo scanner, `nextLine()` bloqueia o programa enquanto aguarda a entrada, porém na segunda iteração do loop um token havia sido  lido por [`java.util.Scanner.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) e então `nextLine()` a partir do ultimo token apenas lê uma linha vazia.
Uma possiblidade de reparo para o seu código é utilizar preceder o uso `nextLine()` com o método [`java.util.Scanner.hasNextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()) que retorna verdadeiro se houver uma linha na entrada do scanner, podedo bloquear  e aguardar enquanto espera por uma entrada.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);    
    String nome="", senha="";    
    do {    
      System.out.println("Digite nome:");
      if(teclado.hasNextLine()){
        nome = teclado.nextLine();
      }
      System.out.println("Digite senha:");
      if(teclado.hasNextLine()){
        senha = teclado.nextLine();
      }
      if (nome.equals(senha)) {    
        System.out.println("Nome deve ser diferente de senha, Digite novamente");
      }
    } while (nome.equals(senha));
  }
}
```

Uma alternativa proporcional a tarefa seria utilizar [`java.util.Console.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine())

```
import java.io.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Console teclado = System.console();
    String nome="", senha="";
    do {
      System.out.println("Digite nome:");
      nome = teclado.readLine();
      System.out.println("Digite senha:");
      senha = teclado.readLine();
      if (nome.equals(senha)) {
        System.out.println("Nome deve ser diferente de senha, Digite novamente");
      }
    } while (nome.equals(senha));
  }
}
```

Comment: Ver se eu entendi, então se eu invez de  senha = teclado.next();  colocar  
senha = teclado.nextLine(); vai da certo?

Comment: Só vai dar certo se colocar `if(teclado.hasNextLine()){nome = teclado.nextLine();}` e `if(teclado.hasNextLine()){senha = teclado.nextLine();}`. A chave para o funcionamento correto é o uso do `teclado.hasNextLine()` que *prepara* o scanner para consumir uma linha com `teclado.nextLine()`.

Comment: Quanto ao `teclado.next()` se por exemplo o usuário entrar com `a b c`, `teclado.next()` só vai ler `a`

Answer (score 2):

Usando o *do-while* dessa forma, sempre irá pedir para redefinir tanto o nome quanto a senha, pois estão no mesmo escopo.
Tomei a liberdade de reescrever seu código, dá uma analisada:

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Digite nome:");
    String nome = teclado.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Digite senha:");
    String senha = teclado.next();

    while(nome.equals(senha)){
        System.out.println("Nome deve ser diferente de senha, digite novamente a senha: ");

        System.out.println("Digite senha: ");
        senha = teclado.next();
        if(nome.equals(senha)) //opcional
            System.out.println("Nome e senha ainda continuam iguais...");
    }
    //só para você ver que deu certo
    System.out.println("nome = " + nome);
    System.out.println("senha = " + senha);
}
```